# how to check if Active Directory server is alive or not in VPN network?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, ping, vpn

I want to check AD is alive or not before doing my tasks.
Everything is ok until I test on VPN network. My Ping method always return false value.
Can anyone suggest me how to ping to AD server in VPN network?

my Ping method

```
public static bool PingToServer(string ipServer)
    {
        bool isServerLife = false;
        try
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(ipServer);

            if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                isServerLife = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Colsole.WriteLine("PingToServer: Cannot ping to server, " + e.Message);
        }
        return isServerLife;
    }
```

Comment: Same as without VPN. Which means your problem is not "vpn" Per se but "crappy network setup". A proper VPN is fully transparent.

Comment: When I do NOT use VPN, my Ping method run normally. When AD is alive, it will return true, and otherwise it return false. But, when my computer use VPN network, i try to test my method again and it always return false despite of AD running

Comment: As I said: Bad setup. No issue with VPN except that your VPN obviously was set up by someone not doing things right. Which is an admin issue. Fix that one instead of programming around an incompetent administrator.